# The largest circle that touches a parabola and $(0,0)$ but does not cross the parabola

Tags: geometry

What is the largest circle (of radius $r(a)$) that touches the parabola $y=ax^2$ ($a$ is a positive real number) and $(0,0)$ but does not cross the parabola ?

I know that the largest circle radius will change if a is changed. The problem is I can't find a condition that makes the circle touch the parabola and $(0,0)$ but does not cross the parabola in mathematical terms. If the circle is too large, it will cross the parabola if we make it pass $(0,0)$.

[image: $]

Comment: There is a theory of local curvature of a planar curve which answers your question, but you need to tell us more about what you know / are allowed to use.

Comment: Intersect the parabola with a circle. You can set up the equation of the circle. It will end up with an easy quartic equation where you want a double root at the origin. Think discriminant. The other 2 roots are irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know much about law and theory in geometry. I know some basic calculus. I will try to understand as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of such a circle is the inverse of the curvature of the parabola at the origin.

The curvature is found to be $2a$ so the radius is $\frac {1}{2a}$

The center of the circle is $(0,\frac {1}{2a})$

Thus the equation of the circle is $$x^2+(y-\frac {1}{2a})^2=\frac {1}{4a^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can derive the condition you are looking for by arguing that the joint equations of the parabola and the circle

$$y=ax^2$$
$$x^2+(y-r)^2=r^2$$

allow only one solution at (0,0), i.e. a single contact point between the parabola and the circle.

After eliminating $x$, you get

$$y(y+1/a-2r)=0$$

which permits only one solution $y=0$ under the condition

$$1/a-2r=0$$

i.e. $r=1/(2a)$. Otherwise, the circle would cross the parabola at $y=2r-1/a$.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are fully right, in the "standard" sense.

But, for the way in which you worded your question,

> the real answer is $r = \infty$.

because any circle tangent to the parabola, at the origin, **from below** will
"touch the parabola and not cross it" !
thereby including the $x$ axis