# Showing the radius of curvature to be $\geq$ radius of the log from which insect is climbing . At highest point

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, curvature

Consider a cylindrical log of radius $R$ which is at rest and a grasshopper is taking a jump from one side of log . Consider the case when the grasshopper is able to jump over it  in the situation where :
It just touches the top most part   path is symmetrical wrt to circular cross section .   [image]

> My question is how do we show that radius of curvature at the time of reaching the highest point is $\geq$ R ? And equality occurs at the time when it reaches top with minimum speed ?

- My main reason for asking is that for the case of touching one i was trying to get the speed at the top , which was given to be √gR. But was not able to show that radius of curvature is exactly same as that of radius of circukar section.

> I think it might be related to proving that there is only one circle which can be tangent a parabola at a  given point such that all other points of parabola are external to it ? How do we prove this ?

Comment: A similar configuration was given at the International Physics Olympiad  in some year IIRC.

Comment: Actually that problem was different in the sense that it asked for minimum speed to go to other side. What i am asking is very different as i am not asking anything related to that speed , i am considering the speed of top point @insipidintegrator

Comment: Radius of curvature for $y(x)$ is given by formula ${\displaystyle R=\left|{\frac {\left(1+y'^{\,2}\right)^{\frac {3}{2}}}{y''}}\right|}$. $y'$ is equal for touching curves in commong point. If $R$ is less for upper curve, then $|y''|$ is greater for upper curve, $y'' <0$, then $y''$ is less for upper curve, then in vicinity of touching point $y=y(a)+y'(a)(x-a)+y''(a)(x-a)^2/2+...$ must be less for upper curve, which is contradictory.

Comment: For last question paragraph: There are infinitely many parabolas tangent to circle in given point. Some of them have 1 common point with circle, other have 3 common point. If you use center of circle as origin and tangent point is $(0;R)$ then general equation of tangent parabola is $y=R+kx^2$. One can find what minimum $k$ gives only one common point with circle. This $k$ corresponds to minimum radius of curvature of parabola in tangent point which must be equal to $R$. There are also tangent parabolas with curvature radius less than $R$ having 1 common point, which are not physical ($k>0$).

Comment: Very nice thanks @IvanKaznacheyeu

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313626/the-largest-circle-that-touches-a-parabola-and-0-0-but-does-not-cross-the-pa/

Comment: Thanks it also clears it

Answer (score 1):

If $a_\perp$ is the projection of the acceleration of the body on a direction perpendicular to its velocity $v$, then we have the kinematical relation:
$$
a_\perp={v^2\over r},
$$
where $r$ is the radius of curvature of the trajectory at the point where the body is located.

At the highest point we have $a_\perp=g$, and $v=\sqrt{gR}$ was given: inserting these into the previous equation we thus get:
$$
g={gR\over r},
\quad\text{that is:}\quad r=R.
$$

Comment: Actually √gR i didnt know from first . I was like trying to prove that to show that indeed then r = R . But i get it from the comments and the links thanks though